The definition of the integral of a function f with respect to a convolution measure is what?
While reading the book "Measure Theory and Probability Theory" by Krishna B. Athreya and Soumendra N. Lahiri, I encountered a problem(Proposition 5.5.4). What does (μ∗λ)(dx) represent and what is its expression?
Proposition 5.4.1: Let $\mu$ and $\lambda$ be two $\sigma$-finite measures on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.
For any Borel set $A$ in $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$, let
$$
(\mu * \lambda)(A) = \int \int I_A(x + y)d\mu(x)d\lambda(y).
$$
Then $(\mu * \lambda)$ is a measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.
Definition 5.5.3: (Laplace-Stieltjes transform). Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $\mu((-\infty, 0)) = 0$. The function
$$
\mu^*(s) \equiv L\mu(s) \equiv \int_{[0,\infty)} e^{-sx} \mu(dx)
$$
is called the Laplace-Stieltjes transform of $\mu$. Clearly, $\mu^*$ is well defined for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$. However, $\mu^*(s_0) = \infty$ implies $\mu^*(s) = \infty$ for $s \geq s_0$.
Proposition 5.5.4: Let $\mu$ and $\lambda$ be measures on $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $\mu((-\infty, 0)) = \lambda((-\infty, 0)) = 0$. Then
$$
L(\mu * \lambda)(s) = L\mu(s)L\lambda(s) \;\; \text{ for all } s \in \mathbb{R}.
$$

Doesn't Proposition 5.4.1 provide an answer to your question? The formula $$\int_{\mathbb R}f(x),(\mu*\lambda)(dx)=\iint_{\mathbb R\times\mathbb R}f(x+y),\mu(dx)\lambda(dy)$$
is true when $f$ is a measurable indicator function, so it should also be true when $f$ is an arbitrary nonnegative measurable function or a $\mu*\lambda$-integrable function.

The Proposition 5.4.1 provides the convolution measure calculation formula for the set A, but it does not provide the integral formula. How did you get the above integral formula for f?

The Proposition 5.4.1 tells you that the formula is true when $f$ is the indicator function of a measurable set $A$, because
$$\int_{\mathbb R}I_A(x),(\mu*\lambda)(dx)=(\mu*\lambda)(A).$$
The linearity of the integral then tells you that the formula remains true when $f$ is a nonnegative simple function. Then, since any nonnegative measurable function can be written as the pointwise limit of an increasing sequence of nonnegative simple functions, the monotone convergence theorem tells you that the formula remains true when $f$ an arbitrary nonnegative measurable function.

I seem to understand, thank you very much for the answer!
